# Why is this rule in Gufw, to prevent Firefox from communicating to a HTTP server, not working?

Tags: firewall, gufw

The rule I'm having problems with is the following:

[image]

After setting it, I'm still able to use Firefox to connect to a HTTP server. Why is that rule not working? From what I understand, the reply of the web server should be denied.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The incoming traffic is NOT using port 80, it uses a random, higher, unpriviled port. The outgoing traffic is however going to port 80 on the server. I  suggest you read a bit on internet protocols and how the firewall works

Comment: @dsstorefile1 As you know, order of rules matters. It is unlikely you can add that rule at the end of the default rule set for ufw as the traffic is accepted by an earlier rule. Otherwise that will work

Comment: @Panther The port 80 is in the **From** part of the form, because it is the source port of the incoming message, which is coming from the web server. I think what you're trying to correct me would apply if I'd typed 80 in the **To** part.

Comment: Ufw probably accepted the traffic earlier in the rule set. It is impossible to debug a single rule in ufw/iltables